# numpy interpolation to increase a vector size

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I have to enlarge the number of points inside of vector to enlarge the vector to fixed size. for example:

**for this simple vector**

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> len(a)
# 6
```

now, I want to get a vector with size of 11 taken the `a` vector as base the results will be

```
# array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ])
```

**EDIT 1**

what I need is a function that will enter the base vector and the number of values that must be the resultant vector, and I return a new vector with size equal to the parameter. something like

```
def enlargeVector(vector, size):
    .....
    return newVector
```

to use like:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> b = enlargeVector(a, 200):
>>> len(b)
# 200
```

and b contains data results of linear, cubic, or whatever interpolation methods

Comment: If the input was `a = np.array([0,-6,1,2,3,7])` and you wanted to call `enlargeVector(a, 7)`, what would your expected output be?

Comment: Are the elements in `a` always equidistant for the consecutive elements? Are you always looking for linear interpolation?

Comment: @Akavall I expect to have a  vector that begins in 0, ends in 7 and have 7 values, well my idea is more that have many many more values, not one or two more values, and the inside datha is the resultant of some interpolations between each value

Comment: @Divakar, not always equidistant but yes they are consecutive, because the are vectors of coordinates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many methods to do this within `scipy.interpolate`. My favourite is UnivariateSpline, which produces an order `k` spline guaranteed to be differentiable `k` times.

To use it:

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
old_indices = np.arange(0,len(a))
new_length = 11
new_indices = np.linspace(0,len(a)-1,new_length)
spl = UnivariateSpline(old_indices,a,k=3,s=0)
new_array = spl(new_indices)
```

The `s` is a smoothing factor that you should set to 0 in this case (since the data are exact).

Note that for the problem you have specified (since `a` just increases monotonically by 1), this is overkill, since the second `np.linspace` gives already the desired output.

EDIT: clarified that the length is arbitrary

Comment: yes I know the `np.linspace` from matlab, but in this case, imagine that you only ant to enlarge your vector to a fixed number of data, something like define a function and use it like `enlargeVector(vector,200)` and return the vector with 200 values, in you solution I don't see where to put the desired length

Comment: mmm, maybe using `np.linespace` in between each value solve my problem

Comment: @efirvida The new length is the third argument to `np.linspace`. I've edited my answer to better reflect this.

Comment: Is there any way to make it for two-dimensional (x,y) coordinates?

Comment: @efirvida There is, but this is a sufficiently different problem to be worth another question.

Comment: Thank I made it in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973766/numpy-interpolation-to-increase-array-size

Answer (score 3):

As AGML pointed out there are tools to do this, but how about a pure `numpy` solution:

```
In [20]: a = np.arange(6)

In [21]: temp = np.dstack((a[:-1], a[:-1] + np.diff(a) / 2.0)).ravel()

In [22]: temp
Out[22]: array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])

In [23]: np.hstack((temp, [a[-1]]))
Out[23]: array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the question is focused on any array with no necessary normal distribution, and what I need is to pass the number of data that I wants to get