# numpy interpolation to increase array size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation

this question is related with my previous question [How to use numpy interpolation to increase a vector size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724546/numpy-interpolation-to-increase-a-vector-size), but this time I'm looking for a method to do increase the 2D array size and not a vector.

The idea is that I have couples of coordinates  `(x;y)`  and I want to smooth the line with a desired number of `(x;y)` pairs

for a Vector solution I use the answer of @AGML user with very good results

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

def enlargeVector(vector, size):
    old_indices = np.arange(0,len(a))
    new_length = 11
    new_indices = np.linspace(0,len(a)-1,new_length)
    spl = UnivariateSpline(old_indices,a,k=3,s=0)
    return spl(new_indices)
```

Comment: Are you interpolating from and to an evenly spaced grid of points?

Comment: , interpolation may be the solution, but I don't know who to specify the desired length of data points

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the function [`map_coordinates`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html) from the `scipy.ndimage.interpolation` module.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import map_coordinates

A = np.random.random((10,10))
new_dims = []
for original_length, new_length in zip(A.shape, (100,100)):
    new_dims.append(np.linspace(0, original_length-1, new_length))

coords = np.meshgrid(*new_dims, indexing='ij')
B = map_coordinates(A, coords)
```

Comment: the desired length will be in the `(100,100)` as `(rows,cols)`??

Comment: Yep, and it will work with higher-dimensional data if you match the length of that tuple to the number of dimensions in the original array.